Unable to parse HTML; parse5 error cde unexcepted-question-mark-instead-of-tag-name
I have upgraded my project from 13 to latest angular 18. In that there is some code of php is done in the index file.
i run my project then error comes that
Unable to parse HTML; parse5 error cde unexcepted-question-mark-instead-of-tag-name

Unable to parse HTML; parse5 error code unexpected-question-mark-instead-of-tag-name
 at /home/projects/stackblitz-starters-r9g8zf/.angular/vite-root/demo/index.html:10:6
8  |    <body>
9  |      <!-- PHP code -->
10 |      <?php echo "welcome to Php landing page" ?>
   |       ^
11 |      <!--          -->
12 |      <!-- App Root -->

Below is the snippet of body tag of html where i just print a string.

 <body>
    <!-- PHP code -->
    <?php echo "welcome to Php landing page" ?>
    <!--          -->
    <!-- App Root -->
    <app-root>Loading...</app-root>
  </body>

Link for the reference to check the error in latest angular 18 having vite development server.
https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-r9g8zf?file=src%2Findex.html
